# Notice: add_to_cart_redirect is deprecated since version 3.0.0! Use woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect instead

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, themes, deprecated

Notice: add_to_cart_redirect is deprecated since version 3.0.0! Use woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect instead public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4924

Notice: WC_Cart::get_checkout_url is deprecated since version 2.5! Use wc_get_checkout_url instead.
public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4648

When i have wp-debug on, i get these errors. Also on phone customers are not able to order through woocommerce store. "Sorry, your session has expired. return to shop" notification has been created.

Where can i change these? Woocommerce works fine on phone aswell if i change from child theme to main theme, but error still exists?

Comment: your theme is outdated with the latest version of WooCommerce. I would suggest you to update the theme to latest version so that the error vanishes. If there's no update then you need to contact the theme author. Or if you want to do it yourself in that case you need to replace the current woocommerce template folder from your theme to the latest one. By that you can override the old instances.